# Create a column that is a sum of the number of dates in a group of columns that come after a particular date, pulled from another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe called that looks similar to this (except the number of 'Visit' columns goes up to `Visit_84` and there are several hundred clients - I have simplified it here)

```
Client    Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Visit_4    ident_date
Client_1  2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-02-10 2018-02-20 2018-01-31
Client_2  2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 2018-03-20 2018-02-31
Client_3  2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 2018-04-20 2018-03-31
Client_4  2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 2018-04-25 2018-04-31
```

I want to create a new column called `vis_sum` that produces a sum of all the visits for each client that come after `ident_date`. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Client    Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Visit_4    ident_date vis_sum
Client_1  2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-02-10 2018-02-20 2018-01-31 2
Client_2  2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 2018-03-20 2018-02-31 1
Client_3  2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 2018-04-20 2018-03-31 3
Client_4  2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 2018-04-25 2018-04-31 0
```

Comment: Feb do not have 31 2018-02-31...

Comment: same for Jan, Mar and Apr.... out of bounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fix your date

```
df.set_index('Client',inplace=True)
#df=df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['new']=df.gt(df.ident_date,axis=0).sum(1)
df
Out[763]: 
            Visit_1    Visit_2    Visit_3    Visit_4 ident_date  new
Client                                                              
Client_1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20 2018-02-10 2018-02-20 2018-01-31    2
Client_2 2018-01-10 2018-01-30 2018-02-10 2018-03-20 2018-02-28    1
Client_3 2018-01-20 2018-04-01 2018-04-10 2018-04-20 2018-03-31    3
Client_4 2018-01-30 2018-03-01 2018-03-10 2018-04-25 2018-04-30    0
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works - I've made a few tweaks so it works with my df, including filtering by columns with the 'Visit' prefix as there are other columns in the df, and, as there is missing data in the ident_date column, I had to add a line at the end that sets new = 0 if ident_date is missing.

Comment: Dates were dummy dates - they're all accurate in the actual df